# unknown local address in TCPView

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I'm looking at connections in TCPView, and I'm seeing "red5" in the "local address" column. This doesn't appear to match any computers on my local network, the names of which I have seen from time to time.

It is only occasionally that I see this, not constantly. Should I be worried about this?

Is there any documentation for TCPView that could provide a better understanding of what this means, or is there a better program that can give me more information on this when it appears in the future?

Comment: What is the IP of `red5`? Can you ping it and it resolve to a known IP? What port is it trying to connect to? Not to speculate but `red` is usually a term denoted to a `red team` (i.e. a security team who's purpose is to find vulnerabilities). Is this part of your home network or work?  .. I wouldn't jump to conclusions as it could just be a known device with a forgotten name (like an old phone) probing the network due to a 'protocol' like [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)  ....

Comment: Home network. It only comes up occasionally, and I haven't had the presence of mind to screen capture it for later analysis

Comment: You could run `wireshark` or the like and capture traffic, then nose through those (possibly verbose) results...